# Why I don't see other type of In-App Purchases in iTunes Connect?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

So I want create new product for my app with type Non-Consumable, but when i click button "Create type" i see only one type "Free Subscription"

[image]

Why do I see only "Free Subscription"?

How can I set "Non-Consumable" for products of app?

Comment: I found this doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW1

This document has description for five type of "In-App Purchases", so why I see only one?
I do not understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it explains itself.

> If a type is missing, make sure you have agreed to all recent
>   contracts.

You must be missing something in the contracts area that you need to complete before the other options will be made available.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but where i can find "contracts area"?

Comment: It's right there when you sign in: "Contracts, Tax, and Banking". There's also a link to it in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: o! sorry, i understood how it do